# Pandas из колонок в строки

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть дф

А мне нужно перевести колонки Comp1...Comp10 в одну колонку Сomp

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите, чтоб итоговая таблица так выглядела? Я не знаю, какая у вас стоит задача, но на втором фото у вас столбец ИД, который как я понимаю должен быть уникальным увеличивается на 1 с каждой строчкой, хотя в оригинальном дф значение было уникально для каждого города, лучше поясните, какая стоит задача, возможно есть более удобные и элегантные способы решить ее.

Comment: Зачем вы удаляете примеры ваших данных из вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу предупрежу-эта функция не использует многие фишки pandas, а соответственно гораздо медленнее, чем могла бы быть, но моих знаний на большее пока не хватает.
Так что если оригинальный датафрейм большой-функция может выполняться долго или вообще зависнуть.

```
list_col = ['Comp1','Comp2','Comp3','Comp4','Comp5','Comp6','Comp7','Comp8','Comp9','Comp10'] #список колонок, которые необходимо преобразовать

def changer(df, columns):
    a = []  # список для городов
    b = []  # список для наименования Comp
    c = []  # список для значения каждого Comp
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        for j in columns:
            a.append(df['Город'].iloc[i])
            b.append(j)
            c.append(df[j].iloc[i])
    df_h = pd.DataFrame({'Город': a, 'Comp': b,'Value': c})
    return df_h

new_df = changer(df, list_col) # функция принимает на вход оригинальный датафрейм и список столбцов
```

В результате выполнения функция вернет датафрейм с 3 столбцами: Город, Comp и Value. Длинна этого датафрейма будет в 10 раз больше, чем у оригинального (тк используем 10 столбцов Comp1-10).